# Add new item to order automatically

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, event-observer

How to add extra product while creating order from admin only. Let's say I added "test1" product from admin, so "test2" product will be added automatically to that order.

I have created Observer for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your `sales_quote_item_set_product` event try this:

```
public function addProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    if ($product->getSku() == 'test1') {
        $added = false;
        $quote = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        foreach ($quote->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getSku() == 'test1') {
                $added = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$added) {
            $addProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $addProduct->load($addProduct->getIdBySku('test2'));
            $quote->getQuote()->addProduct($addProduct);
        }
    }
}
```

If this should be for admin only make sure `sales_quote_item_set_product` is not set globally - it should be placed here:

```
<adminhteml>
    <events>
        <sales_quote_item_set_product>
            ...
```

Comment: but there is an issue if we are removing that test1 product its adding one more time ?

Comment: Mhhh? Can't reproduce ... I can remove "test1" w/o any problems? Maybe another observer?

Comment: after product add to order click on apply coupon button on that button click also that test2 products qty is increasing on every click its changing qty & price

Comment: Please try updated code.

Comment: After add product to order first remove test2 product individually & then remove test 1 product individually you will see  on remove test 2 product is adding there

Comment: Updated again ...

Comment: Perfect you rock