# Added products automatically restrict quantity to 1 in cart and checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, event-observer, addtocart

I have a module that adds a free product to the cart automatically if a product exists.

**The issue:**

1. If the customer keeps shopping and adds other products. The quantity for the free automatic product increases to quantity of 2.

**What I need:**

1. I need the quantity of the free automatic product restricted to 1.  I've tried to code this but I'm unsuccessful.

I can't figure out how to say, If productID is 222 then change quantity to 1 if > 1.  Can someone help?

**Here's the code:**

```
public function addSubAction($observer)
{
    $productId = 123;
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getData('product_id') == $productId) {
            $cart     = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
            $addprod  = 222;
            $qty      = 1;
            $quote    =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
                ->addProduct( Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($addprod), $qty)
                ->save();
            $cart->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, it's same question as this: [Add new item to order automatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179844/add-new-item-to-order-automatically/179846#179846)

---

**Edit:**

Hope I got it ... ;)

- 1st product is the one that gives a free product, your SKU `123`
- 2nd is the free one, SKU `222`, that should be added only one time and only when product `123` is in cart
- additionally `222` is removed, when you remove `123` from cart

Some code I use for a similiar function ...

1. add an observer to `sales_quote_item_set_product`, to add product `222` when `123` is added ...

   ```
   public function addFreeProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
       $product = $observer->getProduct();
       if ($product->getSku() == '123') {
           $added = false;
           $quote = $observer->getQuoteItem();
           foreach ($quote->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
               # check if free product is already added
               if ($item->getProduct()->getSku() == '222') {
                   $added = true;
                   break;
               }
           }

           # add free product once
           if (!$added) {
               $addProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
               $addProduct->load($addProduct->getIdBySku('222'));
               $quote->getQuote()->addProduct($addProduct);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. add an observer to `sales_quote_remove_item` to remove free product when last product `123` is removed from cart ...

   ```
   public function removeFreeProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
       $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
       if ($quoteItem->getProduct()->getSku() === '123') {
           $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

           $freeProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
           $freeProduct->load($freeProduct->getIdBySku('222'));

           $addItem = $quote->getItemByProduct($freeProduct);
           if ($addItem) {
               $newQty = $addItem->getQty() - $quoteItem->getQty();
               if ($newQty == 0) {
                   $quote->removeItem($addItem->getId());
                   $quote->save();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I actually have the part of adding the product and that part works.   The problem is if I add other products to the cart it increases the free product quantity by 1.  So in the cart you will see  product quantity of 2 for the  free product instead of 1.  This happens  because I left the cart and added another product.  I hope that makes  sense.

Comment: @ Brad depends the free product on another SKU? (Or should it always be added?)

Comment: It should always be added.  If $productId = 123; is added then $addprod  = 222; is added with a quantity of 1.   But if you go else where and add another product and go back to the cart the free product (222) has  a quantity of 2.   So I need to check to see if it's already added to the cart IF so then reduce the quantity of 1.

Comment: @brad then this code should work ... `free-product` will be added with the first item you add to cart. If the `free-product` depends on productId 123 e.g., you just add another check ...

Comment: I can't figure out what that check is.  That's the question.   In the code I posted I can't figure how how to check it and change it to 1 if it's greater than 1.  Can you tell me how in the code I posted how to check? I'm new at this.

Comment: @brad OK, i will update this later (1-2h) ...

Comment: @brad update answer. :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not removing any products though.  If they do remove 222, I have code that removes both products 222 and 123.  My issue is when other products are added to the cart it changes the product quantity of the free product from 1 to 2 quantity.  Meaning 2 free products instead of one due to visiting the cart for a second time.  I believe what's happening is the module code that you see above is being activated twice after adding other products a 2nd time.   Does that make sense?

Comment: @brad Have you tested my code? For me this works as you describe.

Comment: No, if I add other types of products and come back to the cart the quantity for 123 has duplicated.  Meaning the quantity in the cart is now 2 instead of 1 for sku 123.

Comment: @brad Sorry, I've no further ideas ... this code does exactly what you want (in my case). BTW .. if you change the the observers in `config.xml` you need to flush cache,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74955/discussion-between-sv3n-and-brad).